# Using Flask-SQLAlchemy to connect to a Microsoft office SQL server, when the server has a backslash in its name

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I've been banging my head against this problem for a couple of hours. To sum it up, I've been trying to connect to a locally hosted MSSQL server using the following code.

```py
server = r'DESKTOP-XXXXX/TEST2'
user = r'DESKTOP-XXXXXYYYYYY'
password = r'something'
db = r'flask_test'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mssql+pymssql://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + server + "/" + db
```

Now as far as I can tell, the problem is with the fact that the server and database on the last line are separated by an '/', which is also present in the server name. As a result, it believes the server name is just DESKTOP-XXXXX, as shown by the error below, when I'm trying to connect to  DESKTOP-XXXXX/test2.

I've tried changing it to a not raw string, changing the slash direction, just entering TEST2,  and many other things but I'm at a loss now. Any help would be appreciated!
Sorry if it seems like a silly problem.

```
File "src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx", line 652, in pymssql._pymssql.connect
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DESKTOP-202JPF7)\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10061)\nDB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DESKTOP-XXXXX)\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10061)\n')
```

Comment: You are correct, the current problem is the `/` slash character. Instance names are delimited from server names using the `\ ` backslash character, so you should be using `DESKTOP-XXXXX\TEST2` in the server variable. This also requires that the SQL Browser service is running on the target machine and that network and firewall rules allow it (the Browser service) to be accessible via UDP port 1434.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response, unfortunately when I switch which slash I use, I get something really similar, here's a snippet! `severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (DESKTOP-XXXXX)\n")`

Comment: Silly questions, perhaps... have you installed an instance of SQL Server? What version and edition is it? Is the SQL Server service actually running? Via the SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for (instance name), have you enabled the TCP/IP protocol?

Comment: So, I have installed and am running a SQL server on the same machine as I'm writing the code. The server edition is 2019, and mssms says the version is 15.0.2000.05. I have indeed enable TCP/IP protocol. I've connected to it before without using SQLAlchemy, using plain pymssql

Comment: Hey everyone, I managed to connect by using the port number instead of the instance name! So instead of `r'DESKTOP-XXXXX/TEST2'`, it was `r'DESKTOP-XXXXX:PortNumber'` for the server field. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It's me, the guy who asked the question, just posting this for future reference. I used the port number instead of the instance name to connect! Like so -

```
server = r'DESKTOP-XXXXX:portnumber'
```

instead of

```
server = r'DESKTOP-XXXXX/TEST2'
```

I believe the '/' was causing problems since it was also the separator for the server name and database name.